# Undefined offset: 0 when using ->with_input() - laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error when using with_input() to keep the user old input data after submiting with validation errors:

ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0

the code for redirect is:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->with_input();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which version of Laravel you are using, but your code should be:

```
return Redirect::to('login')->withInput();
```

and if you are returning errors too, you might consider using `withErrors()` in addition:

```
Route::post('register', function()
{
    $rules = array(...);

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
});
```

Check the docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel 4, you need to use `withInput` instead of `with_input`